# Issues setting up external display

Tags: display, laptop, hdmi

**Solved:**

This was solved with an update that was just pushed.

**The problem:**

I have an XPS 13 (9360) laptop that has an external monitor plugged in through HDMI using a Dell USB-C adapter. Going to Settings->Displays shows the external monitor but enabling it simply gives it a black screen. I can drag my mouse over to the area that was set for the monitor to display in (e.g.: if the monitor was set up to display to the right of me built-in monitor, my mouse could move off the screen to the right). After a few times of fiddling with the display settings, the external monitor would just disappear from the display settings as if it had been unplugged.

**The details:**

- This setup has worked fine on every other distro I have using on this laptop.
- I have tried setting up the external monitor using Arandr as well, with the same issues.
- The monitor *does work* when the resolution is lowered by a lot but that is more of a hacky work around than an actual solution, in my opinion.
- I have also installed all eOS updates and installed the Intel Microcode drivers.

**The hardware:**

- Laptop: https://www.notebookcheck.net/Dell-XPS-13-9360-FHD-i5.184562.0.html
- Adapter: http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-adapter-usb-c-to-hdmi-vga-ethernet-usb-30-da200/apd/470-abqn/pc-accessories (ignore the bad reviews, mine is working fine)
- External display: https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824005150

**The begging:**

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated. I really want to continue using eOS but this bug will probably push me back to something else if I can't find a solution.

**Solved:**

This was solved with an update that was just pushed.

Comment: If the issue doesn't exist anymore with the latest update, you may put that as an answer and mark it as accepted

Comment: I put it as an answer but it won't let me accept my own answer for 48 hours after I have made it.

Comment: Forgot about the grace period, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An eOS system update was just pushed and seems to have solved this issue. The monitor now displays with the proper resolution. Setting monitor positions and primary/secondary settings is still really jank but it is possible to work with it until everything is right.